# SCSS file isn't compiling properly VScode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am a new programmer and just decided to start a new project of building myself a portfolio website using HTML and CSS. I have been reading some books on it, and am following through some tutorials to help myself learn and get results. However, the scss file doesn't seem to be showing any results? I have looked around and tried everything Ican, I am new at this so it takes me a while to understand how to look for what's wrong, but any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: What's your file structure?

Comment: Did you run `npm run build` or `npm run webpack` or something similar after your SCSS was ready?

Comment: @RichardHenage `npm` is required if you compile server sided with `node.js`. VSC compiles directly and generates CSS files directly if you lose focus on the code block through extensions.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @chovy I dont get an error message but my changes aren't reflected in the html file